# PHP: Unable to echo values from nested Array in PHP

Tags: php, wikipedia-api

I want to echo data which is in JSON format. I converted from JSON to PHP array using json_decode() but it is not getting echoed. Blow is my code:

```
<?php
$url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts|info&exintro&format=json&explaintext&titles=google";

//retriving JSON data using get_file_contents

$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json);

$pageid = $data->query->pageids[0];
echo $data->query->pages->$pageid->extract;
?>
```

I only needed extract data which contains information for that title.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the request in the browser, you will see that the returned JSON does not contain a pageids property, but is of the form

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {  
        "normalized": [  
            ...
        ],
        "pages": {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If all you want is to grap the extract from the first item, you could do:

```
<?php

$url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts|info&exintro&format=json&explaintext&titles=google";

//retriving JSON data using get_file_contents

$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json);

$page = reset($data->query->pages);
$extract = $page ? $page->extract : null;
```